# Is there a memory penalty to use a string rather than a StringBuilder inside a loop?

Tags: java, performance

I have this testing loops:

```
String str_1;
Object an_object_var = new Object();

long startTime = System.nanoTime();

for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{
    an_object_var=(Object)i;
    str_1 = an_object_var.toString();            
}

long endTime = System.nanoTime();

long timig = endTime - startTime;
System.out.println(timig);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
an_object_var = new Object();

System.out.println(new Date());

startTime = System.nanoTime();

for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{
    an_object_var=(Object)i;
    sb.delete(0, sb.length());
    sb.insert(0, an_object_var);
}

endTime = System.nanoTime();

timig = endTime - startTime;
System.out.println(timig);
```

I'm not concateanting the string, just making some unboxing. The first loop is a lot faster than the second one (15441625 vs 26869129 nanoseconds. I'm running them on NetBeans). But, as long as Strings are inmutable, I'm creating 100000 variables in memory in the first loop (until the next Garbage Colector pass).
Is there a memory penalty in the first loop that doesn't happen in the second loop?

Comment: You are implicitly calling an_object_var.toString() in your second loop. Of course, it'll be slower since you're calling other methods in addition...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since garbage collector doesn't allow memory leak, there's no memory penalty because this statement:

```
str_1 = an_object_var.toString();
```

will cause GC to release the old string object before changing the reference.
EDIT:someone said you can't claim gc will do that, well even if so you can determine yourself like this:

```
for(long i = 0; i < 1000000000000; i++)
{
   an_object_var=(Object)i;
   str_1 = an_object_var.toString();            
}
```

I doubt a memory can survive that !

Comment: One cannot claim that GC would release the old `String` object at any particular time during the run of the program. GC can wait for au unspecified period of time before releasing all these `String` and `Integer` objects created in a loop.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight but how will he catch the old reference and release it, the reference gone, does he move all along the memory ? or does he store the reference for later processing ?

Comment: GC will catch the old reference when it runs the next time on its own schedule, not at the exact moment when the last reference is gone. There is no reference counting going on - GC knows about top-level reachable objects, and traverses the graph to find out what else is reachable. Whenever it finds something that's no longer reachable, it reclaims its memory.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the difference is that the compiler can eliminate more code form the first example, because it doesn't do anything useful.  The second loop is harder to optimise away to nothing.

Another problem you have is that the first loop triggers the whole method to be optimised, in this case the JIT has no information on the second loop so it can't optimise it as well.  I suggest you put both tests in their own method and run then a number of times.  Make sure the test runs for at least 2 seconds each.

BTW If you used

```
sb.setLength(0);
sb.append(i);
```

instead of

```
an_object_var=(Object)i;
sb.delete(0, sb.length());
sb.insert(0, an_object_var);
```

this would avoid creating any garbage.

Comment: tell me if I'm wrong: as long as the compiler optimizes the code, it will not create 100000 strings in memory despite they're inmutable, right?

Comment: @Broken_Window it will only discard the Strings if it can determine they are not needed and don't have any side effects. (Called Escape Analysis) The fact they are immutable doesn't make a difference.  You are better off writing the code so it doesn't need a String in the first place, then this is nothing to eliminate.